# How to add case statement to add break after every record?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, line-breaks, sql-like

There should be a break after every row `LIKE 'A%'` when find next records of `LIKE 'B%'`.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM fistevent WHERE Event_Id=? AND TicketType=? AND row_name REGEXP '^[A-Z]' ORDER BY row_name ASC");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['EventId'],$_POST['TicketType']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
if($numRows > 0) {
    echo ' <div class="register">';
    while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $EvntId = $r['Event_Id'];
        $RowName = $r['row_name'];

        echo '<ul id="sub" class="sub">';
            if($r['seats'] == null){ 
                echo '<li class="BlankSeat" ></li>';
            }elseif($r['Status'] == 'Y' || $r['Status'] == 'Hold'){
                echo '<li class="occupied" title="Row'.$r["seats"].'" name="'.$RowName.'" value="'.$r["seats"].'"></li>'; 
            }else{
                echo '<li class="Available" title="Row'.$r["seats"].'" name="'.$RowName.'" value="'.$r["seats"].'"></li>';
            }
        echo "</ul>";
   }
   echo '</div>';

I am getting the following output, but I want after `LIKE 'A%'` the next `LIKE 'B%'` should be in the next row.
```

[image]

**Updated code is here**

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM fistevent WHERE Event_Id=? AND TicketType=? AND row_name REGEXP '^[A-Z]' ORDER BY row_name ASC");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['EventId'],$_POST['TicketType']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
if($numRows > 0) {
    echo ' <div class="register">';
    $prev='A';  
    while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $EvntId = $r['Event_Id'];
        $RowName = $r['row_name'];
        if($prev!=$RowName){
            echo "<br>";
            $prev=$RowName;
        }
        echo '<ul id="sub" >';
            if($r['seats'] == null){ 
                echo '<li class="BlankSeat" ></li>';
            }elseif($r['Status'] == 'Y' || $r['Status'] == 'Hold'){
                echo '<li class="occupied" title="Row'.$r["seats"].'" name="'.$RowName.'" value="'.$r["seats"].'"></li>'; 
            }else{
                echo '<li class="Available" title="Row'.$r["seats"].'" name="'.$RowName.'" value="'.$r["seats"].'"></li>';
            }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo '</div>';
}else{
    echo "No seats Available";
}

**in responsive**
```

[image]

Comment: @mickmackusa sir  I just want to add break after LIKE 'A%' records .

Comment: @mickmackusa sir.take a look on updated code .see what i execute from this code

Comment: @mickmackusa sir. i also update the database table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should add line breaks between (not before the first) each unique row, and add the `row_name` letter to the start of each unique row.

```
$prev='';
while($r=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($prev!=$r['row_name']){
        if($prev!=''){echo "<br>";}                             // add breaks between rows
        echo "<ul id=\"sub\" class=\"sub\">{$r['row_name']} ";            // label the row
        $prev=$r['row_name'];                                 // store new row_name letter
    }else{
        echo "<ul id=\"sub\" class=\"sub\">";   // not a new row_name, extend existing row
    }
        if($r['seats']==null){ 
            echo "<li class=\"BlankSeat\"></li>";
        }elseif($r['Status']=='Y' || $r['Status']=='Hold'){
            echo "<li class=\"occupied\" title=\"Row{$r['seats']}\" name=\"{$r['row_name']}\" value=\"{$r["seats"]}\"></li>"; 
        }else{
            echo "<li class=\"Available\" title=\"Row{$r['seats']}\" name=\"{$r['row_name']}\" value=\"{$r['seats']}\"></li>";
        }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

To overcome the OP's `li {float:left}` styling, he has made this adjustment in the css:

`ul{display: table-cell; }`

---

Old answer starts here:

I don't know how Bijender's answer helped you, and I don't know why you need a function call.  I also don't know what you mean by "add break after LIKE 'A%".

Since `row_name` is a single letter value, and you want to only return rows with the value A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, or J, then you will want this simpler / more refined query:

```
SELECT *
FROM fistevent
WHERE Event_Id=? AND TicketType=? AND row_name IN ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J')
ORDER BY row_name ASC
```

The error that I found in your post is that your table column is either `EventId` or `Event_Id`.  You should fix this typo for clarity.

Comment: first of all Thank you very much for the reply sir. i just updated my code as you say in query. i want that when loop gets all record of 'A%' after that the next 'B%' must be starts in next row.thats what iam asking about

Comment: @krish This seems to be a styling issue.  Do you have css that is impacting this code?

Comment: @mickmackusa .. #seatarea {
    padding-top: 30px;
 width:100%;
 
}
ul{
 margin-left:3%;
}

li { 
    width:27px;
    float:left;
 list-style: none;
 
}

Comment: @mickmackusa sir .i added ul{display: table-cell; } and it is working

Comment: @mickmackusa yes sir its all good .You are very intelligent and wise man.thanks alot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145768/discussion-between-krish-and-mickmackusa).

Comment: @krish  I am now off to bed.  I have tried to condense and clean up my answer, leaving only the important bits.  I have deleted most of my comments now as they will only contribute to page bloat.  Please consider removing your comments that are not particularly educational to future readers.  Please also review my final edit that there is nothing incorrect -- I don't want to leave any bad info on SO.  Thanks for your cooperation on your question.  I like to see people getting resolution on SO.

Comment: ...oh and I just realized after reviewing your question that `row_name` is a single letter value, so the (less efficient) `REGEXP` expression can be replaced with `IN`  -- see my edit.  I mean, you _can_ use the REGEXP expression, I didn't realize you needed to go all the way from A to Z.  Are there other values in this column that you actually don't want to match?  If the each value in the column is only one character, you can remove the `^` in the regex pattern.  If the column has more than just A-Z values, perhaps it would be better to target that smaller list of values and deny them.

Comment: @mickmackusa sir when i open it in mobile or tab..means in responsive manner it make row separate like above in the picture.want to fix A,B,C,D,E with the row li

Comment: @krish It is for this exact behavior that I avoid styling with float.  It is too unpredictable on the thousands of different devices and browsers.  You might just ask a new question if you can't solve it on your own.

Comment: Sir could you please tell me .why php is not shwoing on my webpage?

Comment: Please tell me the filename including suffix AND copy/paste the file's content into a pastebin or sandbox link and I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Since you order by row_name you only need to check if the new value is different from the previous value.

```
//setting firstLetter
$firstLetter = '1';
  while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $EvntId = $r['Event_Id'];
        $RowName = $r['row_name'];


       echo '<ul id="sub" class="sub">';
        if($r['seats'] == null)
        { 
        echo '<li class="BlankSeat" ></li>';
        }
        else if($r['Status'] == 'Y' || $r['Status'] == 'Hold')
        {
        echo '<li class="occupied" title="Row'.$r["seats"].'" name="'.$RowName.'" value="'.$r["seats"].'"></li>'; 
        }
        else
        {
         echo '<li class="Available" title="Row'.$r["seats"].'" name="'.$RowName.'" value="'.$r["seats"].'"></li>';
        }
        //comparing current first letter with previous first letter,also skipping the break if it is the first row
         if($RowName[0] != $firstLetter &&  $firstLetter !='1'  ){
         echo "<br />";
        }
        $firstLetter = $RowName[0];

       echo "</ul>";
       }
```

Comment: I see there was some discussion on another answer containing inferences of plagiarism of this answer. I don't think that's constructive, so I've reported all related comments to a moderator. FWIW, I think it's OK for people to use an answer as the basis of their own anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for `like` in php

```
function like_match($pattern, $subject)
{
    $pattern = str_replace('%', '.*', preg_quote($pattern, '/'));
    return (bool) preg_match("/^{$pattern}$/i", $subject);
}
```

Example

```
like_match('%A','Apple'); //TRUE
like_match('%c', 'coop'); //TRUE
like_match('%l', 'deke'); //FALSE
like_match('%m', 'flip-flop'); //FALSE
```

Comment: I just make the code shorter like this.select all the matching records.

Comment: using query - $stmt = $con->prepare("select * from fistevent WHERE  Event_Id =? And TicketType=? order by row_name ASC");

Comment: now how can i add a break when it gets record of name B or C or D..Is that possible to add in case

Comment: @mickmackusa sir .when row letter changes the next letter starts from the next line..