# First time enter 5 in input then after enter 4 blank rows.now if i enter 3 in input now row should be start from 6 to 8 in database

Tags: php, html

**This is my code** 
    I created a form to save rows in database first time i add 5 records in database and then i want to enter 3 or 4 blank rows and then i want to add 5 or 6 rows and they must start from my first counring like now they start from 6 .

```
 <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control-own" id="row_id" name="row_id">
     <input type="text" class="form-control-own" id="row" name="row">
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit1" value="Save">
    </form>
```

> **This is Php Code**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
$RowId=$_POST['row_id'];
$Rows=$_POST['row'];
for($i = 1; $i <= $Rows; $i++)
    {
    $insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table1(rowId,rows)VALUES('".$RowId."','".$i."')");
echo "<h1> Saved</h1>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not get why you want to do that (it looks like illogical). Can you explain why you want to do that?

Comment: @Neodan sir. iam working on a seat selection project on backhand i need to add available seats then some blank rows and then again available seats. we cannot count blank row as a seat number .thats why i need  to use such query

Comment: Reseach `mysqli prepared statements` because your query doesn't look secure.  Bloating your database with empty rows of data is not good practice.

Comment: @mickmackusa sir here i just post a demo what i want to this code.otherwise iam using PDO for sql injection

Comment: `name="row_id"` versus `$_POST['row-id']`

Comment: @Jeff sir..i don't understand .can you please add your code with my existing

Comment: the name of the input is `row_id`, but you try to get the value via `$_POST['row-id']`. Thats different. A Typo. `row_id` vs. `row-id`. (not that this will solve all your problems, but it is one of them)

Comment: @Jeff sir  sorry but it is here by mistake but in real code it is ok as in input same name in post..problem still existing

Comment: you never said what your exact problem is by the way...

Comment: @Jeff sir.i think i mention my problem in heading.

Comment: @mickmackusa sir .Is there any alternate solution for this? if yes please suggest me..

Comment: We don't understand enough about your project to confidently provide an answer.  Can you give more details on the overall scope of this project?  I mean is there an infinite number of seats/rows?  Or can it be fully booked?  What would be the benefit of storing blank rows?  Are you trying to preserve certain spaces?  Perhaps show us an image or map of seats.  Please edit the question.

Comment: @mickmackusa sir..iam gonna show you  my retro question.thats how my project look like ..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340615/how-to-add-case-statement-to-add-break-after-every-record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going use standard form fields as the user interface, I would probably go with a multi-select box that lists `A1,A2,A3... B1,B2... etc`  This will keep the UX pretty simple and intuitive, specifically while selecting neighboring seats in a row.

Alternatively, you would really pretty-up your interface to lay [the seat map from your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340615/how-to-add-case-statement-to-add-break-after-every-record) and over a series of cleverly-positioned checkboxes.  This will require more careful development when designing across many devices and browsers.

You will have to build in additional considerations if you have to contend with Seat Statuses like "Reserved" and "Paid For". Otherwise, you should have the simple handling of seats being "Unavailable" -- because there is a row in the database table that matches `EventID` & `SeatID`; or "Available" -- because there is no row that matches the particular `EventID` & `SeatID`.

I don't really see the benefit of separating `Row Letter` from `Seat Number` in your database.  If it helps you in any way to keep them separate, that's fine.  I think I'd have just two Primary Keys on the table: `EventID` and `SeatID`.  The `SeatID` would be a letter followed by (optionally zero-padded) digits.  For example:

- if you have less than 10 seats per row: `A1`, `A2, ...`B1`...
- if you have less than 100 seats per row: `A01`, `A02`, ... `B01`, ...

By giving each seat a unique ID, you avoid the requirement to bloat your database with empty rows to "position" the available and unavailable seats.

Even if you have gaps between seats in each row, this doesn't matter from a database design perspective.  Just assign SeatIDs and everything should become programmatically easier.